# Go to code location in VS extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've got a VS editor extension, and when the user performs a certain action, I'd like to send them to a specific location in the code- not unlike Go To Definition or what happens when you click on a stack frame in the debugger.

So far, I used dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile to open the actual file, and I have the relevant ITextDocument, but I don't know how to set the view to the relevant place in the file. It seems like ITextView and IVsTextView and friends have the methods that I need but I'm unsure how to get the instances I need from my ITextDocument.

How can I go to the file and location I want from a VS extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to take the return of `ItemOperations.OpenFile` and navigate from it to the `IWpfTextView`

```
IWpfTextView GetWpfTextViewForDteWindow(
    Window window,
    System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
    IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService vsEditorAdaptersFactoryService)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(window.Document.Path, window.Document.Name);

    IVsUIHierarchy vsuiHierarchy;
    uint itemID;
    IVsWindowFrame vsWindowFrame;
    if (VsShellUtilities.IsDocumentOpen(
        serviceProvider,
        path,
        Guid.Empty,
        out vsuiHierarchy,
        out itemID,
        out vsWindowFrame))
    {
        // Note this may have multiple IVsTextView instances associated with it in a split window but 
        // this will retrieve at least one 
        var vsTextView = VsShellUtilities.GetTextView(vsWindowFrame);
        var wpfTextView = vsEditorAdaptersFactoryService.GetWpfTextView(vsTextView);

        return wpfTextView;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Do note that there is not necessarily a 1-1 mapping between a DTE `Window` object and `ITextView` instance.  The `Window` object essentially represents what is visually displayed as a tab and a given tab can contain many `ITextView` instances.  The most common case is when there is a horizontal split in the window.  Probably doesn't matter too much for this scenario but wanted to make sure that it got called out

Comment: For me, I'm pretty sure that as long as the location is available in *some* ITextView and that ITextView is active, then I get about the intended behaviour. Thanks for this. Did I mention that I seriously hate VS extensibility? (Also, your method takes an IServiceProvider but never uses it).

Comment: @DeadMG the `serviceprovider` parameter is used in the `IsDocumentOpen` call.  Yeah VS extensibility can be a real pain sometimes.  I often feel like I need a treasure map of some sort to correctly navigate from various representations of the exact same object.  So frustrating